# Clicked once disabled, Clicked 5 times do something else

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I created a React [flashcards app](https://norden-flashcards.netlify.app/planets) for my son, where clicking on a card disables it. I wanted to make it so that if he clicks the same card five times, like "Mercury," it opens a Google Images search for that [item](https://www.google.com/images?q=mercury). However, I've been facing issues getting this functionality to work.

I've tried

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getColor } from "./utility/colorUtils.js";
import { playAudio } from "./utility/audioUtils.js";
import { getPageName, goHome } from "./utility/pageUtils.js";

import "./Category.css";

const Category = ({ type }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [clickedItemName, setClickedItemName] = useState("");
    const [clickedItems, setClickedItems] = useState([]);
    const [slideText, setSlideText] = useState("");
    const [clickCounts, setClickCounts] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const jsonData = require(`./data/${type}.json`);
        setData(jsonData);
    }, [type]);

    useEffect(() => {
        playAudio(clickedItems.length, data.length, goHome);
    }, [clickedItems.length, data.length]);

    const handleClick = item => {
        setSlideText("");
        const thumbnailId = item.name.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
        const clickedThumbnail = document.getElementById(`${thumbnailId}`);

        setClickedItemName(item.name);

        if (!clickedThumbnail.classList.contains("disabled")) {
            speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(item.name));
            clickedThumbnail.classList.add("disabled");

            setClickedItems(prev => [...prev, thumbnailId]);
            console.log(clickedItems);

            // Update clickCounts for this item
            setClickCounts(prevClickCounts => ({
                ...prevClickCounts,
                [item.id]: (prevClickCounts[item.id] || 0) + 1,
            }));

            console.log(clickCounts);

            switch (clickedItems.length + 1) {
                case 1:
                    setSlideText("");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    setSlideText("");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    setSlideText("");
                    break;
                case 15:
                    setSlideText("✨");
                    break;
                case 20:
                    setSlideText("⭐️");
                    break;
                case 25:
                    setSlideText("️");
                    break;
                default:
                    setSlideText("");
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ((clickCounts[item.id] || 0) === 5) {
            window.open(`https://www.google.com/images?q=${encodeURIComponent(item.name)}`, "_blank");
            setClickCounts(prevClickCounts => ({
                ...prevClickCounts,
                [item.id]: 0,
            }));
        }
    };

    //https://pixabay.com/sound-effects/search/celebration/

    return (
        <div className="category-page" style={{ overflowX: "hidden" }}>
            <nav className="breadcrumbs">
                <Link to="/" className="home-link">
                    Go Home
                </Link>
                <span onClick={() => goHome()} className="breadcrumb-divider">
                    {" "}
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; / &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                </span>

                <span onClick={() => goHome()} className="current-page">
                    <img src={`/images/types/${type}.png`} alt="Icon" className="icon" width="20" /> {getPageName(type)}
                </span>

                <span className="float-right selected">
                    <a href={`https://www.google.com/images?q=${encodeURIComponent(clickedItemName)}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        "{clickedItemName}"
                    </a>
                </span>
            </nav>

            <div className={`thumbnails-container`}>
                {data.map((item, index) => (
                    <div
                        key={index}
                        id={`${item.name.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase()}`}
                        className="thumbnail"
                        onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: getColor(item),
                        }}
                    >
                        <div className="name-initial">{item.name.charAt(0)}</div>
                        <div className={`thumbnail-details`}>
                            <h6>{item.name}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            {slideText && (
                <div className="slide-up">
                    <p>{slideText}</p>
                </div>
            )}

            {data.length === clickedItems.length && (
                <div className="achievement-container">
                    <img src="/images/1.gif" alt="achievement" className="achievement" />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Category;
```

Reproducible Link:
https://norden-flashcards.netlify.app/planets

Comment: Note that you can create [Stack Snippets that use JSX and React](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552)...

Comment: "I've been facing issues" is not a good description of the details of problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why subsequent clicks do not work:

First of all,

```css
.thumbnail.disabled {
  pointer-events: none; /* Category.css:29 */
}
```

... makes the element unable to receive pointer events. Once a `.thumbnail` becomes `.disabled`, clicking on it means clicking on the background, through it.

And secondly, you're only updating `clickCounts` inside:

```js
if (!clickedThumbnail.classList.contains("disabled")) {
  // here...
}
```

...which becomes `false` after the first click on the thumbnail, stopping the count at `1` for any clicked thumbnail (even if the thumbnail didn't have `pointer-events: none`).

Basic example doing what you're after:

```js
const App = () => {
  const items = ['Airplane', 'Helicopter', 'Glider']
  const [clicks, setClicks] = React.useState({})
  const onClick = (item) => {
    setClicks((prev) => ({ ...prev, [item]: (prev[item] || 0) + 1 }))
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const item = items.find((item) => clicks[item] > 4)
    if (item) {
      console.log(
        `Should open "https://www.google.com/images?q=${encodeURIComponent(
          item
        )}" in a new tab`
      )
      // window.open(`https://www.google.com/images?q=${encodeURIComponent(item)}`, "_blank");

      // reset clicks on item !?
      setClicks((prev) => ({ ...prev, [item]: 0 }))
    }
  }, [clicks])
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items.map((key) => (
        <div
          {...{
            onClick: () => onClick(key),
            key,
            className: clicks[key] ? 'faded' : ''
          }}
        >
          {key}
        </div>
      ))}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ clicks }, null, 2)}</pre>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
#root > div {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1; 
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
#root > div.faded {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```